# How to align multiple elements to one main element with format strings in swift

Tags: ios, swift, visual-format-language

I am trying to perform the following task that is shown with the following image

This is what I have as far as constraints go so far, the "Entertainment" string is represented by the **categoryLabel** and the "Disney: build it frozen" by **nameLabel**.

[image]

```
addConstraints(withFormat: "H:|-8-[v0(90)]-8-[v1]-8-|", views: imageView, nameLabel)
addConstraints(withFormat: "V:|-8-[v0(90)]", views: imageView)

addConstraints(withFormat: "H:[v0]-8-[v1]", views: imageView, nameLabel)
addConstraints(withFormat: "V:|-8-[v0]-8-[v1]", views: nameLabel, categoryLabel)

func addConstraints(withFormat format: String, views: UIView...) {
    var viewsDictionary = [String: UIView]()
    for (index, view) in views.enumerated() {
        let key = "v\(index)"
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        viewsDictionary[key] = view
    }

    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: format, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
}
```

The problem I am having is how to add the "categorylabel" to the constraints such that it is aligned to right of the imageView by 8 pixels and directly under the nameLabel by 8 pixels. As you can see from the screenshot I can achieve placing it below the nameLabel but I am having a hard time making it such that the "categorylabel" is to the right of the image view as well.

Any tips would be very much appreciated :)

What I want it to look like
[image]

Comment: Is there a reason you're laying this out programmatically? You might find it substantially easier to lay this out using `UIStackView`. https://www.raywenderlich.com/114552/uistackview-tutorial-introducing-stack-views. It's available from iOS 9 and later.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up but as easy as this task would be doing it through storyboards but I am trying to achieve it programmatically.

Comment: Could you provide a picture of the way it's _supposed_ to look?

Comment: absolutely, Just wondering if there was a way to do it all in one line like I have with `addConstraints(withFormat: "V:|-8-[v0]-8-[v1]", views: nameLabel, categoryLabel)` but for the horizontal side of things except I have 3 elements I need to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately by wrapping `NSLayoutConstraint.constraints` in your own function, you have prevented access to the feature you need, which is to specify the `.alignAllLeading` `NSLayoutFormatOptions` to your nameLabel-category constraint.

Essentially, what you need is:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-8-[v0]-8-[v1]", options: .alignAllLeading, metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
```

This will tell autolayout that you want the leading edges of the two items to be aligned and separated vertically by 8.  Since you already have your name field positioned relative to the edge of the image view, this will put your category field where you want it.

You can re-factor your `addConstraints` function to accept NSLayoutFormatOptions:

```
func addConstraints(withFormat format: String, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions = NSLayoutFormatOptions(), views: UIView...) {

var viewsDictionary = [String: UIView]()
    for (index, view) in views.enumerated() {
        let key = "v\(index)"
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        viewsDictionary[key] = view
    }

    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: format, options: options, metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
}
```

and then call it:

```
addConstraints(withFormat: "V:|-8-[v0]-8-[v1]", options: .alignAllLeading, views: nameLabel, categoryLabel)
```

By the way, you don't need to use storyboards to use stack views.